# Red and green inks in printers

Tags: digital-printing, ink

I have an older Canon 9000 printer which has tanks for Red and Green ink (alongside the traditional CMY tanks). However, it is difficult to find Green Ink refills. Does anyone know why professional printers have green ink, rather than mix cyan and yellow?
Thanks

Comment: Some photo printers often have more than just CMYK inks because it helps increase the number of printable colours (the colour gamut) - ultimately providing better quality colour prints.

Answer (score 1):

> why professional printers have green ink, rather than mix cyan and yellow?

It is not rather, but besides.

Some greens will have a combination of cyan and yellow, and some other greens will have more green ink.

The reason is that it widens a bit the total gamut of the colors it can print.

Here is a fake diagram of this expanded gamut.

[image]

Forgive the $? characters. They were to explain that sometimes the extra inks does not justify the additional cost.